# Scrapy extracting empty td values although there are no empty values in table

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I built a spider for crawling one individual site:
www.docteur.ch/generalistes/generalistes_k_ag.html

It crawls the td of a table with the following format:

```
<table class="novip">
        <tr class="novip">
          <td class="novip-portrait-picture"
            rowspan="5">
            <a class="novip-portrait-picture"
              href="/medecin/baumberger-hans-rudolf-aarau-5000-medecin.html">
              <img class="novip-portrait-picture"
                src="/customer_controlled/pictures/65903/portrait/65903.png"
                alt="Pas d'image encore"
                onError="portrait_m_image_failover(this)" />
            </a>
          </td>
          <td class="novip-left">
            <a class="novip-firmen-name"
              href="/medecin/baumberger-hans-rudolf-aarau-5000-medecin.html"
              target="_top">
              Baumberger&nbsp;Hans Rudolf
            </a>
          </td>
          <td class="novip-right"
            width="25%">
            <a class="novip"
              href="/medecin/baumberger-hans-rudolf-aarau-5000-medecin.html"
              target="_top">
              rating info:&nbsp;              <img class="novip-inforating"
                src="/img/general/stars/stars3 "
                alt="rating info"
                width="70" height="14" align="bottom" border="0" />
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="novip">
          <td class="novip-left">
            Dr. med. Facharzt FMH f&uuml;r Allgemeine Innere Medizin
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="novip">
          <td class="novip-left">
            Bahnhofstrasse&nbsp;92, 5000&nbsp;Aarau
          </td>
          <td class="novip-right-telefon">
            t&eacute;l:&nbsp;062 822 46 28
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="novip">
          <td class="novip-left-email">
            e-mail:&nbsp;
            <a class="novip-left-send-message-button-inactive"
              href="/eintrag/fr_keine_mitteilung_moeglich.html">
              Envoyer un message
            </a>
              &nbsp;
            <a class="novip-left-make_appointment-button-inactive"
              href="/eintrag/fr_kein_termin_moeglich.html">
              prendre un rendez-vous
            </a>
          </td>
          <td class="novip-right-fax">
            fax:&nbsp;062 822 35 20
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

I just want to extract the individual Name of the doctor with the following code:

```
import scrapy

from docteur.items import DocteurItem


class DocteurGeneralistSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "docteur_generalist"
    allowed_domains = ["docteur.ch"]
    start_urls = [
    'http://www.docteur.ch/generalistes/generalistes_k_ag.html',
    ]


    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//table/tr[@class="novip"]'):
            item = DocteurItem()
            item['name'] = sel.xpath('.//td[2]/a[@class="novip-firmen-name"]/text()[normalize-space()]').extract_first(default='not-found')
            #item['phone'] = sel.xpath('.//td[@class="novip-right-telefon"]/text()[normalize-space()]').extract_first()
            yield item
```

I extract the name but for every entry also two empty fields, although there are no empty td in the source code of the page

```
    [{"name": "\n              Baumberger\u00a0Hans Rudolf\n            "},
{"name": "not-found"},
{"name": "not-found"},
{"name": "not-found"},
{"name": "\n              Bettschart\u00a0Robert\n            "},
{"name": "not-found"},
{"name": "not-found"},
{"name": "not-found"},
....]
```

What is the problem with my code? How can I extract only cells that have values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get all the name:

```
 names = response.xpath('//table/tr[@class="novip"]//a[@class="novip-firmen-name"]//text()').extract()
```

It returns just the 467 names:

```
In [14]: names = response.xpath('//table/tr[@class="novip"]//a[@class="novip-firmen-name"]')

In [15]: len(names)
Out[15]: 467
```

You get empty results as you are checking all the trs so when you don't find one with `class="novip-firmen-name"` you get your default value outputted.

If we take  the first few you can see what us happening:

```
In [23]: for sel in response.xpath('//table/tr[@class="novip"]')[:5]:
             print(sel.xpath('.//td[2]/a[@class="novip-firmen-name"]'))
   ....:     
[<Selector xpath='.//td[2]/a[@class="novip-firmen-name"]' data=u'<a class="novip-firmen-name" href="/mede'>]
[]
[]
[]
[<Selector xpath='.//td[2]/a[@class="novip-firmen-name"]' data=u'<a class="novip-firmen-name" href="/mede'>]
```

If you search for just the anchor tags that have `class="novip-firmen-name"` you get what you want:

```
 In [38]: for sel in response.xpath('//table/tr[@class="novip"]//a[@class="novip-firmen-name"]')[:5]:
         print(sel.xpath('.//text()').extract_first().strip())
....:     
Baumberger Hans Rudolf
Bettschart Robert
Bock Andreas
Brändli Heinrich
Buchser Marcel
```

Or  you  can search for the tds that have anchor tags with the class you want to get those tds:

```
In [39]: for sel in response.xpath('//table/tr[@class="novip"]/td[a[@class="novip-firmen-name"]]')[:5]:
             print(sel.xpath('./a/text()').extract_first()).strip()
   ....:     
Baumberger Hans Rudolf
Bettschart Robert
Bock Andreas
Brändli Heinrich
Buchser Marcel
```

Comment: I believe you mean "You get empty results as you are checking all the TRs", not all tds. Another way to filter the TRs in each table is to take the first class match, i.e. `//table/tr[@class="novip"][1]` (in this particular case for this website of course)

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. I could implement it but have two questions for my understanding. This code will only get the values for one name? If I would like to extract let's say the phone numberas well I would need to built the XPath differently?  How does the // before the td[a[@class="novip-firmen-name"]]' work? How is it different from a single /?  Thank you!

Comment: @Jan,  what do you not understand?

Comment: Sorry, I was not finished writing and hit the enter button accidentally

Comment: @Jan, that actually only needs to be a single slash, a double will allow you to find a descendant, in this case we are looking for a child so a single / is sufficient.

Comment: Another way to get  just the  anchors would be `'//table/tr[@class="novip"]/td/a[@class="novip-firmen-name"]'`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @Padraic's answer using CSS selectors:

1. for each table, select the first child row, with class "novip"
2. within each row, select anchor with class "novip-firmen-name"

In scrapy shell:

```
>>> for row in response.css('table.novip > tr.novip:first-child'):
...     print("----------")
...     s = row.css('a.novip-firmen-name').xpath('normalize-space()').extract_first()
...     pprint(s)
... 
----------
u'Baumberger\xa0Hans Rudolf'
----------
u'Bettschart\xa0Robert'
----------
u'Bock\xa0Andreas'
----------
u'Br\xe4ndli\xa0Heinrich'
----------
u'Buchser\xa0Marcel'
----------
u'B\xfchlmann\xa0Severin'
----------
u'Dang\xa0Linh'
(...)
----------
u'Vonesch\xa0Hans-J\xfcrg'
----------
u'Koppe\xa0Dagmar'
>>>
```